# App crashed when taking photo

Tags: android, android-camera

I am making an android activity that could show the preview of the camera. I tried to capture that photo directly without calling another camera apps (in another word, I do not wish to use intent).

The apps crashes when I click on the Stop Preview button. I added the codes for capturing photos with the stop preview. Below is my source code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CameraOpened extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

 Camera camera;
 SurfaceView surfaceView;
 SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
 boolean previewing = false;
 static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
 int count;
 PictureCallback rawCallback;
 ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
 PictureCallback jpegCallback;
 private final String tag = "VideoServer";

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_opened);

       Button buttonStartCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startcamerapreview);
       Button buttonStopCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopcamerapreview);

       getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
       surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
       surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
       surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
       surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

       buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

           public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!previewing){
             camera = Camera.open();
             camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
             if (camera != null){
              try {
               camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
               camera.startPreview();
               previewing = true;
              } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
              }
             }
            }
           }});

       buttonStopCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(camera != null && previewing){
             camera.stopPreview();
             camera.release();
             camera = null;
             previewing = false;
             captureImage();

             rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
                 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                     Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
                 }
             };


             shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
                 public void onShutter() {
                     Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
                 }
             };
             jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
                 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                     FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                     try {
                         outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                                 "/sdcard/DCIM/jgjk.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                         outStream.write(data);
                         outStream.close();
                         Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } finally {
                     }
                     Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
                 }
             };
            }
           }});
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camera_opened, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
   int height) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
 private void captureImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }


}
```

The logcat for my app is below:

```
10-21 15:51:06.343: V/ContextImpl(9564): ----- packageName = com.camera is NOT LOCKED -----
10-21 15:51:07.743: D/Camera(9564): [CTA] Camera open urrentpackagename = com.camera
10-21 15:51:07.753: D/Camera(9564): [CTA] Camera open application != null
10-21 15:51:07.753: D/Camera(9564): [CTA] check CTA permisson mAllowUsing = false
10-21 15:51:07.753: D/Camera(9564): [CTA] Camera open urrentpackagename = com.camera
10-21 15:51:07.753: D/Camera(9564): [CTA] Camera open application != null
10-21 15:51:07.753: D/Camera(9564): [CTA] after check permission mAllowUsing = com.camera
10-21 15:51:08.803: I/Choreographer(9564): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-21 15:51:11.453: D/AndroidRuntime(9564): Shutting down VM
10-21 15:51:11.453: W/dalvikvm(9564): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430f9140)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564): Process: com.camera, PID: 9564
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at com.camera.CameraOpened.captureImage(CameraOpened.java:155)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at com.camera.CameraOpened.access$0(CameraOpened.java:153)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at com.camera.CameraOpened$2.onClick(CameraOpened.java:79)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4487)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18746)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
10-21 15:51:11.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9564):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 15:51:14.223: I/Process(9564): Sending signal. PID: 9564 SIG: 9
10-21 15:51:14.493: I/dalvikvm(9811): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
10-21 15:51:14.493: W/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11390: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
10-21 15:51:14.493: D/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
10-21 15:51:14.493: I/dalvikvm(9811): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
10-21 15:51:14.493: W/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11396: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
10-21 15:51:14.493: D/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
10-21 15:51:14.503: I/dalvikvm(9811): Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
10-21 15:51:14.503: W/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8966: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
10-21 15:51:14.503: D/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
10-21 15:51:14.503: I/dalvikvm(9811): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
10-21 15:51:14.503: W/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 366: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
10-21 15:51:14.503: D/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-21 15:51:14.503: I/dalvikvm(9811): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
10-21 15:51:14.503: W/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 388: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
10-21 15:51:14.503: D/dalvikvm(9811): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-21 15:51:14.563: E/IMGSRV(9811): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
10-21 15:51:14.563: E/IMGSRV(9811): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
10-21 15:51:14.563: E/IMGSRV(9811): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 51
10-21 15:51:14.563: E/IMGSRV(9811): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 51
10-21 15:51:14.563: E/IMGSRV(9811): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 51
10-21 15:51:14.573: E/IMGSRV(9811): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 53
10-21 15:51:14.593: D/OpenGLRenderer(9811): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Why the app crashes and fail to capture photo?

Comment: Post your LogCat output.

Comment: What exactly is the exception you're getting? Please include the exception trace in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reminder. I have added the logcat.

Comment: You call `captureImage()`, and after that, you populate the listeners. First set the listeners, then call `captureImage()`

Comment: LJoosse: I changed it according to your comment but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You probably send null as parameter on:
`camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);` (Line 155)
The reason is that you initializes your shutterCallback, rawCallback and jpegCallback inside the onClickListner, try to do this inside the 'onCreate' methode, but outside the onClickListner block.

Comment: How shall I solve the problem. It would be great if you give me a clear guidance.